# Reference on quantization of linearized gravity

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, quantum-gravity, linearized-theory

I often see claims saying that quantization of linearized gravity can be done. Is there some standard references for it? such as original papers/ review papers / textbooks etc.

Comment: I think the best modern reference is this thesis - https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0410097v1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classic papers that started the field are these three from 1967 by [Bryce DeWitt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bryce_DeWitt):

B. DeWitt, *Quantum Theory of Gravity. I*, Physical Review, 160:1113–1148, 1967.

B. DeWitt, *Quantum Theory of Gravity. II. The Manifestly Covariant Theory*, Physical Review, 162:1195–1239, 1967.

B. DeWitt, *Quantum Theory of Gravity. III. Application of the Covariant Theory*, Physical Review, 162:1239–1256, 1967.

The third paper discusses a variety of interesting calculations, including the cross sections for gravitational scattering of two scalar particles, the scattering of gravitons by scalar particles, graviton-graviton scattering, two-graviton annihilation of scalar-particle pairs, and graviton bremsstrahlung.

In the manifestly covariant approach, the calculations are Feynman-diagram-style, with a propagator for gravitons and vertex rules for how gravitons interact with scalars and with themselves. It looks like QED except with a lot more indices and a lot more terms, but no gamma matrices because he’s using scalars instead of fermions for the “matter”.

The algebra for even these tree-level calculations is onerous and he omits the details. It probably took him months if he did it by hand. Today one would let a computer algebra system crank through it in less than a second.

As you probably know, this approach to quantum gravity is non-renormalizable and therefore not of interest as a “real” theory. But it should be fine at low energies.

Comment: Here is a 2006 paper comparing photon and graviton calculations, presented in an accessible way. It includes the fermion-graviton vertices. https://scholarworks.umass.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.com/&httpsredir=1&article=1277&context=physics_faculty_pubs

Comment: do you have suggestions for more modern reviews? With, in particular, discussions on quantization linearized gravity will be great.

Comment: Here is a 2002 review: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5255540/#!po=0.793651